# Graph request returns nil after login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using facebook ios sdk 4.1

And i am using this code to get user's info after user click button and login

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {


        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                println("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                var fbuseremail = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
                var fbfirstname = result.valueForKey("first_name") as! NSString
                var fblastname = result.valueForKey("last_name") as! NSString
                var fbusername = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString

             //....more code
```

But result.valueForKey("email") and others returns nil

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get user info in facebook sdk 4.x swift

```
@IBAction func btnFBLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.containsObject("email"))
            {
                self.getFBUserData()
                fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }
        }
    })
}

func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                println(result)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Output :

```
{
    email = "ashishkakkad8@gmail.com";
    "first_name" = Ashish;
    id = 910855688971343;
    "last_name" = Kakkad;
    name = "Ashish Kakkad";
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/10394859_900936369963275_5557870055628103117_n.jpg?oh=fefbfca1272966fc78286c36741f9ac6&oe=55C89225&__gda__=1438608579_9133f15e55b594f6ac2306d61fa6b6b3";
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: i get "Set<NSObject> does not have a member named 'ContainsObject'" error

Comment: at where? @RULE101 I have added code for custom fb button login

Comment: fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.containsObject("email") should be fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email") i guess ???